# ieframe.dll and shlwapi.dll lack in dependency walker

Tags: c#, .net, dll, virtual-machine, dependency-walker

I try to run a .net desktop project on Oracle VM but it does not run. I tried to see missing resources on "dependency walker". ieframe.dll and shlwapi.dll are marked as red. When I added these resources, I faced to face with warnings for some other dll. resources. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem. This is just a false positive from Dependency Walker. You should ignore this. Don't attempt to package up and redistribute these DLLs. Simply ignore what Dependency Walker says. Your application's loading will not be affected by these particular false positives. Whatever changes you have made to any machines relating to these two DLLs should be reversed.

Note that Dependency Walker is designed for unmanaged executables. For .net executables it is less useful. You may need to find a different tool to diagnose your problem.

Comment: I understood. Well! What about ieshims.dll? There is yellow marked "?" and error message as "Error opening file. The system cannot find the file specified." Are there any solution about it?

Comment: Same with `ieshims.dll`. False positive. What's missing from the question is an error message.

Comment: I checked the windows logs too, but there is no error about it.

Comment: Why are you looking at error logs. You say that your program does not run. What errors are shown when it fails to start.

Comment: I thought that maybe I can understand that did the program started or not. May be the program had started but my code failed. May be it needs some installation with .Net framework.

Comment: Does your program start or not? If it does not, what error message is shown when you attempt to start it? Please will you answer the questions that I ask you. If you continue to ignore my questions, I will stop helping you because there is no longer any point in my doing so. It's only fun helping people that want to be helped.

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice your question. There is no error message. Only a window open and close quickly.

Comment: Sounds like your program is running and terminating immediately. If the program was failing to load you'd see an error dialog. I suggest some debugging. In the meantime, I think that I answered the question that you asked.

Comment: FWIW, I wasn't actually trying to help solve your problem (you did not present your problem), I was attempting to answer the question that you asked. Did you perhaps ask the wrong question?

Comment: May be. I will review the situation again. Thank you again.

Comment: I don't think you really understand how Stack Overflow works.